# TensorFlow: How to swap the rolls of a graph's inputs and weights?

Tags: tensorflow

In [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/), is there an easy way to take a [`Graph`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/framework.html#core-graph-data-structures) object, and turn all (or some) of its [`placeholder`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#placeholders)s to [`variable`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#variables)s, and all (or some) of its [`variable`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#variables)s and [`Tensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/framework.html#Tensor)s to [`constant`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/constant_op.html#constant)s (or [`placeholder`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#placeholders)s)?

In other words, I would like to take a (trained) neural network, preserve its computational graph structure, but to optimize over the placeholders, while keeping the weights constant.

### Edit

As an example, given the simple neural network from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.12/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_softmax.py):

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
y = tf.matmul(x, W) + b
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(y, y_))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)
```

I would like to transform it into:

```
x = tf.Variable(tf.float32, [None, 784])
W = tf.constant([values of trained weights],shape=[784, 10])
b = tf.constant(,shape=[10])
y = tf.matmul(x, W) + b
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(y, y_))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)
```

where `[values of trained weights]` are the values of `W` and `b` after training the original network. I interested whether there exists an easy automatic way to perform such a transformation.
(Note: I haven't ran the above example, so it may contain mistakes)

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you have a trained network, shouldn't it already have a specific input size? How can you "optimize over the placeholders"? `placeholder` and `variable` are interchangeable. `Placeholder` is specified by `feed_dict` at runtime while `Variable` needs to be initialized when you declare it.

Comment: @user3813674 I have a network that performs classification, with placeholders as inputs, weights as variables, and certain nodes (tensors) in the graph as outputs. Also there are placeholders for the true class (which is used for training). Lets assume that I've trained this network. Now I want to operate it "reversely" - I choose a "true" class, give the network some initial (possibly random) input, and optimize (gradient descent) on that same input, keeping the weights constant, to get the smallest lost. This is a method for forcing the input to become more like the chosen class.

Comment: Can you post a minimal version of what you are describing?

Comment: @user3813674 Here.

Comment: @user3813674 placeholder and variable are not interchangeable. They have totally different uses. Placeholders are data given to the graph, variables are trained over time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there answer is "No, there is not an easy way". Even your simple example is kinda complicated. You've got placeholder to variable, variable to constant, and placeholder to placeholder. How would some automatic method know when to convert to what when you have placeholders converted only part of the time? Sounds like you would have to implement something yourself. As a start, you can at least get a list of variables using `tf.trainable_variables()`. `x.assign()` returns an op you can use to assign values to variables. Maybe those will help somehow towards a more automatic solution.

As for the idea in general of "I have a class, what was the likely input" - you may want to check out probabilistic programming. That sounds pretty close to what your goal is. For those, you have a bunch of data/labels, and you write a model that generates the labels. The language constructs a sampler for your model, and you can ask questions about different pieces of the model, similar to your question: "I have classes, what must the inputs have been?"

Here's an intro if you're interested: https://probmods.org/. Sounds like https://github.com/blei-lab/edward might be in this area too.